# Google Analytics Reporting API profile permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I get an error using default [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4).
I have added a new service account with Owner permissions in Google Cloud. Then created a JSON key, copied the email of the account, and added it as Administrator inside the GA console under the "Administration" tab.
After all that I copied the view ID, set the path to the JSON file, and got an error: `User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile`.
I have no idea what is wrong.
Also using Data API works well, but I need reporting API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the admin section of Google Analytics for the account you want to access.

Take the service account email address its the value with a @ in it and add it as a user of the account it will then have access

Comment: I did this but still get the same error

Comment: then you didnt add it to the correct account.   "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile"  it doesnt have access to the profile you want to access under that account.